# Facebook API pagination

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I have an app that gets all list of friends of a user using:

```
FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=id,first_name,last_name,birthday,gender,picture];
```

It used to work great in the past, but it no longer functions well (I get only the first few friends).
I did some digging and noticed that Facebook added pagination to the response.
I really not need the pagination and want to take all friends list at once.
There is also no reason for me to call Facebook all the time again and again in order to get all the list of friends.
I tried using the "limit" parameter with no luck. It simply doesn't work (at least not for "999" or "5000" values).

How can I overcome this issue that didn't exist in the past?

Comment: Did it just stop working? You can always file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Filing a bug takes ages with Facebook and they usually do not treat it from my past experience. I have no problem adjusting myself to the new API. I just don't understand why there is no longer a way of getting the list of all my friends at once. It is not reasonable to make 100 requests using paging just to get all my friends.